sending a redirect response from aws lambda edge function based on the status of origin response
Recently, we created a image optimizing service which returned stream of converted file after uploading the same to s3.
The flow would be something like this,
file-request ---> s3 ---> labda edge --(if status != 200)-> resizing service
                                  ^----(if status == 200)-> the s3 response

Due to limitation of edge functions we were unable to stream the file which were greater than 1.33MB. as a workaround, resizing service redirected to the public url of s3 file and it doesn't seem to work.
approaches used to solve this problem,

return the streamable file -- limited to 1.33MB
redirect to newly resized public ur -- doesn't seem to work
return streamable file and write to s3 -- which might work after first call(as it is written to s3 in first request)
return the public url -- not feasible as of now because the call is being sent by the <img /> from browser


Note: resizing service is built with Nestjs and lambda edge is configured for origin reponse of s3

The desired approach is the redirected one, as getting higher limit is always conservative
